# Merge two Google Groups together?

Tags: google-groups

I currently have two [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com): A and B. Is there any way to merge these two groups together and move all the people in group B into group A?

There are some people who are in both groups, so ideally the solution would handle duplicates.

*I did find [one solution](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/contacts-and-sync/ohBQ5cwM5jY), but I couldn't find the 'groups tab' the answer referred to. I suspect that answer referred to an older version of Google Groups, but if not and I'm just overlooking it, could somebody provide a more detailed breakdown of what to do?*

Comment: The referred solution is regarding groups in [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com) that could be accessed directly from the Gmail web UI, not for [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. Google Groups has no such feature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't really merge the groups into a whole group, but you can nest one under the other, which will allow the nested group to receive all of the emails and default settings of the parent group.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/167100?hl=en

Comment: Nesting groups is only available for Google Groups for Business, not for the consumer edition.