# Merging of Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge two Google Groups together?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30526/merge-two-google-groups-together)

How do I merge two Google Groups together?

Like import the members of one group into the other?

For example:

- 1400 members in group A
- 300 member in group B

Then I want to merge the people in group B into group A.